# Jest encountered an unexpected token with Next.js Babel Typescript and Swiper

Tags: typescript, jestjs, next.js, babel-jest

I have a fresh installation of "Next.js with Jest+Babel" from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest-babel

I've also installed Swiper: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper

Just creating a very simple test, instantiating Swiper on Home, I've been getting this:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/index.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/Users/xxx/with-jest-babel-app/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js:13
import { Swiper } from './swiper.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | // import { Mousewheel, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper'
> 2 | import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
    | ^
```

I know this is a common issue with tons of forums and posts about it, but I could not make it work here so far.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions ("Here's what you can do: …")? What error message(s) did you get if they didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I am still missing something.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: no @theineffablebob, as far as I've been reading, it's a known and existent bug, but I haven't tried it lately really...